# Word 2010 custom XML?

Tags: xml, ms-word, word-2010

I am looking into a new project which involves adding XML structure to a Word document using Custom XML but I don't know how the i4i case affects this.

1) Microsoft recommends using custom controls in the document. Can this validate using an XML Schema file? It looks to me more like a way to create a template and not really for adding tags to existing content.

2) The i4i judgement about Custom XML only concerned North America. Did Microsoft remove the feature worldwide or can I still access it in Australia?

Comment: You are correct on point 1. You can use sdt's to tag content if you want, but its not designed for validating your tags against a schema.  Whether this is a good approach will depend on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are alternative approaches and which I covered in my blog [Windward Wrocks](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2010/02/custom-xml-for-word-and-the-i4i-patent-case.html) (links and better formatting at my blog):

> Custom XML for Word and the i4i patent case Windward Reports never
>   used Custom XML (or bookmarks) for tagging. (We looked at both but
>   each approach has issues that make them problematic at times.) But we
>   do use tagging in Word, Excel, & PowerPoint as our report designer. We
>   do have a very powerful Office AddIn to support this tagging. So I
>   think I have as good an understanding of the issues around this as one
>   can have and yet still be a disinterested party.
>
> I'm not going to give an opinion on the case except to say I wish they
>   could have reached an agreement. The big losers on this are everyone
>   who made use of Custom XML for tagging as this is now removed. (And to
>   say a pox on all software patents.)
>
> First for the programmers who have to adjust, there is a product from
>   i4i that hacks around this called x4w. However, I don't think that is
>   your best solution (explained below). My suggestion is to switch to
>   using content controls, fields, bitmaps, and/or plain old text. The
>   first three of these approaches are more robust than custom XML and
>   are still supported by Word. We use all four approaches (user
>   selected) and they are rock solid.
>
> So what do you do if you have custom XML in your Word documents? If
>   you don't use the custom XML, then there's no problem, just open the
>   files and Word will strip it out, leaving you the rest of the
>   document. Same if your use can be switched to using another feature.
>   You will lose your existing markers but otherwise can continue.
>
> If you need to find any files that have custom XML in them, this
>   program for Microsoft will do the job (DOCX/DOCM only). Also, this
>   restriction only comes in to play for Word 2007 sold on or after 11
>   January this year – and all copies of Word 2010. Microsoft has a good
>   summation here.
>
> If you must have the custom XML, your only option at present is x4w.
>   However, I strongly recommend that you only use this as a stop-gap
>   measure as you find an alternative to custom XML. Because you could
>   find that the next service pack of Word will render x4w unable to save
>   your custom XML. As there is no love lost between Microsoft and i4i, I
>   would not be surprised to see in the next service pack:
>
> 1.Word drops support for custom XML. At present it strips the custom
>   XML out but when it is inserted back in, Word still has the
>   functionality to display and use it. But if custom XML support is not
>   allowed, they can then remove that functionality from Word. 2.Word
>   strips custom XML on saving as well as on loading a document. If this
>   occurs i4i can try to hack around this too, but this is a much more
>   difficult problem. And for cases that the hack fails, you won't know
>   until the next time you open the file – and all your work is lost.
>   3.Word changes at what point during the load process that it strips
>   out the custom XML. It presently occurs before the open document event
>   (which I assume is when x4w inserts the custom XML back in). But Word
>   could strip it out right after that event – and it is then a much
>   harder hack to get the custom XML back in.

Answer (score 0):

On 2), technically it would be legal, but MS did not consider it worth the additional effort, and nor would I.